# JQuery - adapt method .live() to plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm new to JQuery and I tried using a JQuery plugin in my project but had no success.
Someone told me that the error will be fixed if I use the method .live() with the event "load" but I can not implement it. Anyone Can help me adapt the method?

My JQuery version is 1.4.2.

I need adapt the method here(i guess):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#slider").easySlider({
                     auto: false, 
                     continuous: true
                   });      
        });
</script>
```

The plugin (just out of curiosity):

http://pastebin.com/56xxqK5i

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: `live` has been removed in the latest jQuery. If the plugin hasn't been updated then it won't work properly, try using a previous version of JQ.

Comment: Hi guy! I'm using the version 1.4.2 of JQuery. I need to use it anyway.

Comment: .live() method is used to attach event handlers for current and appended elements. There is no event here in your code to be attached, so I don't understand why would you need to do that.

Comment: I need of the event "load". Help me.

Comment: Just a sanity check, but is jQuery being included on the page before the plugin?

Comment: Yes, was included before :)